# How to create a UIBarButtonItem in UIViewControllerRepresentable Struct?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to add a button in my custom navigation bar, Problem is when I am adding bar button item to the navigation bar it doesn't allow me to create an @objc method, to avoid it I created a different class for objc methods but that doesn't seem to work either, code accepts the selector method but doesn't trigger when tapped during runtime.

Plan is to launch a Side menu on the Tap of this button, The button is added and visible, but the action doesn't work, any work around or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
struct CustomNavigationBar: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return CustomNavigationBar.Coordinator(parent: self)
}

// Properties
/// Ease of Use
var view : AnyView
var title : String  //Will be location of the user

/// On Search and On Cancel Closures
var onSearch : (String) -> ()
var onCancel : () -> ()
var didTapMenu : () -> ()

// Require Closures on initialization
init(view: AnyView, title : String, onSearch : @escaping (String)->(), onCancel : @escaping () -> (), didTapMenu : @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.view = view
    self.title = title
    self.onSearch = onSearch
    self.onCancel = onCancel
    self.didTapMenu = didTapMenu
}

// Integrating UIKit Navigation Controller with SwiftUI View
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
    
    //Requires SwiftUIView
    let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: childView)
    
    // Navigation Bar Data
    controller.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
    controller.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    // Navigation Bar Customization
    controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(Color.grubSoulRed)
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    controller.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: 17)!]
    
    //Adding Navigation Button // ===> Problem Here
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "hamburgerMenu"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(navigationActions.hamburgerTapped(_:))) 
    childView.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton

    
    
    // Search Bar
    let searchController = UISearchController()
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here for products..."
    /// Search Bar Customization
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 17
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    /// Setting search bar delegate
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
    /// Adding Search Bar
    controller.navigationBar.topItem?.searchController = searchController
    controller.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    
    return controller
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {

}

// Search Bar delegate
class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    
    var parent : CustomNavigationBar
    
    init(parent: CustomNavigationBar) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.parent.onSearch(searchText)
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.parent.onCancel()
    }
}}

open class navigationActions {
@objc func hamburgerTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
    print("hamburger tapped")
    // Launch Hamburger menu
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a new class,
Declare `hamburgerTapped` function inside the `Coordinator` class and set the target as `Coordinator` class and access from the `Coordinator`

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "hamburgerMenu"), style: .plain, target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.hamburgerTapped(_:))) // <--- Here!!
```

and inside the `Coordinator` class

```
// Search Bar delegate
class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
    // Other code
    @objc func hamburgerTapped(_ sender : UIButton) { // <-- Here!!
        print("hamburger tapped")
        // Launch Hamburger menu
    }
}
```